# Update only specific data in Realtime database of Firebase v9

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to firebase and using ReactJs, I am wondering how can I update a specific data in Realtime database, I want to change the value of it to true or false interchangeably.

[image]

This is my code.

```
  const [status, setStatus] = useState(false);
  const [tempId, setTempId] = useState("");
  const [todo, setTodo] = useState("");
  
  const updateStatus = () => {
    update(ref(db, `/${auth.currentUser.uid}/${tempId}`), {
      completed: setStatus(!status),
      todo: todo,
      id: tempId,
    });
  };
```

Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to update the status property, you can do:

```
update(ref(db, `/${auth.currentUser.uid}/${tempId}`), {
  completed: !status
});
```

Since your calling `update`, it will leave the other properties of the node unmodified.

---

Alternatively, you can do:

```
update(ref(db, `/${auth.currentUser.uid}/${tempId}/status`), !status)
```

Or:

```
set(ref(db, `/${auth.currentUser.uid}/${tempId}/status`), !status)
```

Both of these write to the complete path of just the `status` property.

---

What you'll note is that I don't call `setStatus` in the code above. Instead I recommend [listening to the value](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#web_value_events) of the status node, and then calling `setStatus` when you get a callback there:

```
onValue(ref(db, `/${auth.currentUser.uid}/${tempId}/status`), (snapshot) => {
  setStatus(snapshot.val());
});
```

Separating the read and write operations like this is known as [command query responsibility segregation (or CQRS)](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html) and in the case of Firebase won't even be slower for the user, as the local SDK will immediately call the `onValue` handler when you call `set` or `update` on that path.